# Constantes vacías en PHP CLI

Tags: php, cli, constantes

La consulta es la siguiente.
Quiero usar mi index.php mediante CLI pero no me toma ninguna constante que haya definido y tengo muchas.

Por ejemplo, tengo una constante definida para indicar la ruta a ciertos archivos

```
define("MASTER", "mi_ruta");
```

y si luego quiero imprimirla, está vacía!

```
echo "mi ruta: ".MASTER;
```

Devuelve

"mi ruta:" cuando en realidad debería ser "mi ruta: mi_ruta" el resultado.

Busqué y no encontré nada que me indique que las constantes definidas en PHP NO funcionen en CLI.

Debo activar algo en apache especialmente?

Desde ya, gracias!

EDIT 1:

```
| => php -q "/RUTA_AL_ARCHIVO/index.php"
mi ruta:/________________________________________________________________________________
```

Eso es lo que obtengo.

EDIT 2:
En realidad, estoy haciendo un echo ya que varias constantes definen rutas internas y no las toma.

Comment: Creo que tienes que llamar primero al archivo donde tienes las constantes definidas, de lo contrario no podrá funcionar.

Comment: si tienes la constante y la concatenación e impresión de la misma en el mismo archivo debería funcionar, si tienes dicha constante en otro archivo entonces deberás hacer un require de este a donde lo quieras usar; por que te debería funcionar sin problemas

Comment: Apache no entra en juego en ese escenario, no podría ser debido a su configuración.

Comment: ¿esta mostrando los errores? hay variables como algunas de $_SERVER que no están disponibles en CLI, es posible que alguna parte del código no se ejecute y por eso no se cargan las constantes.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas! no obtengo ningún error. Simplemente no las toma. @element la constante está en otro archivo con include_once, no con requiere. Eso influye? al momento de llamar al index, me incluye el archivo ya que el echo lo hago allí y responde. Es rarísimo! y no encontré a nadie que le pase que no puede leer constantes en CLI.